# Visual force Page to search account by Name and should be able to select number of records as part of result

Tags: visualforce, controller

User wants to search Account records by Name
and User should be able to select number of records as part of result
If user selects Page Size 2 then System should retrieve only 2 account records.
User should be able to set page size as 2, 5, 10, 20 and 50

I am done with the search part and facing issues setting the page size based on user input

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="SearchRecords">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputText value="{!getstring}" id="theTextInput"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!searchRecords}" value="Search" id="theSearch"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(createFriendList!=null, true, false)}">
                <apex:pageBlocktable value="{!createFriendList}" var="records"> 
                    <apex:column value="{!records.fname__c}" headerValue="Firstname"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!records.lname__c}" headerValue="LastName"/>
                </apex:pageBlocktable>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class SearchRecords {

    public string getstring{get;set;}
    public string setstatus{get;set;}
    public List<MyFriends__c>createFriendList {get;set;}

    public void searchRecords(){
        createFriendList= new list<MyFriends__c>();
        if(getstring!=null){
            createFriendList= Database.query('select id,fname__c,lname__c from MyFriends__c where lname__c like \'%'+getstring+'%\'');                    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need to fix the [SOQL injection vulnerability](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm) in your code.

Comment: In addition to KeithC's statement which is IMPORTANT, simply add a limit clause to your SOQL based on the selected size to solve your issue. I do not see where you are even passing the size to a class property though.

Comment: To add to Eric's comment, read up on SOQL Offset (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm)